# How can invoke a shell to make a new environment to run a make inside another make?

Tags: recursion, gnu-make

I would like in my GNUmakefile to have a target rule that invokes a new shell and then with the clean slate of the new shell invokes a new make.

What is the syntax to do this?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:
 shell cd myDir; make; cd ..
```

It gets infinite repeat of the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/disk4/home/user/parent'
shell cd myDir; make; cd ..
/bin/sh: shell: command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/disk4/home/user/parent'
shell cd myDir; make; cd ..
/bin/sh: shell: command not found
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parens are not necessary. Every line in a recipe is invoked in its own shell anyway. Your recipe seems to have a superfluous *shell* string, which your shell tries to execute as a command (/bin/sh (your shell, *not* make) complains `shell: command not found`).

Also, make's `-C` parameter is handy in this case.

Also, when calling make from the shell, use the `${MAKE}` macro.

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:
    unset MAKEFLAGS; ${MAKE} -C myDir
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(cd myDir ; make)
```

The parens invoke a new subshell, with its own "current directory".

Comment: The new subshell is inheriting something from the parent because the (cd myDir; make) behaves differently than invoking that from the top outside the makefile with this rule for setup.

Comment: Yes, it will inherit all exported variables. Use `env` if you want to prevent even this.

Comment: Please elaborate on how env is used.  Is it 'env -i' somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:
 (cd myDir; env --unset=MAKEFLAGS make)
```